# Best way to know if a user is still logged in using msal-browser

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I previously used the `GetAccount` function in `msal` 1.x.

Now, my understanding is that, `msal-browser` will return a cached `Account`, even if the user is logged out.

`acquireTokenSilent` will also return a non-expired cached token even if the user is no longer logged in.

So what is the best way to know if a user is still logged in in B2C?

Additionally, can a logged-out user still exchange a refresh token for an access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.So what is the best way to know if a user is still logged in in B2C?

MSAL.js will not keep track of the currently signed in account.So we can only know if the user has logged in, but cannot know if they are still signed in.Because when you want to sign the user out of the application, it isn't enough to clear the application's cookies or otherwise end the session with the user. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#sign-out).

> 2.Additionally, can a logged-out user still exchange a refresh token for an access token?

As long as the refresh token does not expire, a logged-out user can get the access token.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if the user is logged-in in app A and B. Then log out from app B (calling B2C end session endpoint). There is no way from app A to know that the user is logged out of B2C?

Comment: Yes, there is no way, login to different apps is independent of each other.